# Chrome extension that applies pasted coupon codes on local website doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension that will alow user to paste a bunch of coupon codes seperated by a spacebar into extension's textarea, and after clicking check coupons it should check them on the website untill it sees any change in the price of a $ sum in website's checkout or runs of out coupons to try.

**After typing anything into the extension's textarea and clicking Check Coupons nothing happens. It should by my understanding check coupons untill the price reduces, and give me information which coupon was the one that worked**

The website I've build has couple of items with prices, a total sum, and place to enter coupons. There are 3 coupons in the website's script.js that will reduce the price of a total sum.

The website is being run on node js local server.

**website's html and js**

https://codepen.io/paulshepherd/pen/oNQNjdL

Coupon SUMMER2023 reduces the price of a cart's SUM $

**Extension's html, js and manifest.json**

https://codepen.io/paulshepherd/pen/WNYNQPY

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const checkButton = document.getElementById('checkButton');
  const couponCodesInput = document.getElementById('couponCodes');
  const resultMessage = document.getElementById('resultMessage');

  checkButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const couponCodes = couponCodesInput.value.trim().split(' ');

    if (couponCodes.length === 0) {
      resultMessage.textContent = 'No coupon codes entered.';
      return;
    }

    checkCouponCodes(couponCodes);
  });

  function checkCouponCodes(codes) {
    let currentIndex = 0;

    function checkCode(index) {
      if (index >= codes.length) {
        resultMessage.textContent = 'No working coupon code found.';
        return;
      }

      const code = codes[index].trim();

      if (code.length === 0) {
        checkCode(index + 1);
        return;
      }

      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'applyCoupon', coupon: code }, (response) => {
          if (response.success) {
            resultMessage.textContent = `Coupon ${code} works! You can use it on this website to buy things cheaper!`;
          } else {
            checkCode(index + 1);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    checkCode(currentIndex);
  }
});
```

I understand there might be a lot of wrong with this.

This is first time I work with extensions, I will be happy to get any kind of help.

Comment: Relevant code belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto external platforms. [mre]

Comment: @CBroe right, sorry for that